# A question regarding verb parallelism from GMAT

Tags: conjunctions, passive-voice

This is a question from GMAT sentence correction section.

\begin{question}

The growth of the railroads led to the abolition of local times, which was determined by when the sun reached the observer’s meridian and differing from city to city, and to the establishment of regional times.

(A) which was determined by when the sun reached the observer’s meridian and differing

(B) which was determined by when the sun reached the observer’s meridian and which differed

(C) which were determined by when the sun reached the observer’s meridian and differing

(D) determined by when the sun reached the observer’s meridian and differed

(E) determined by when the sun reached the observer’s meridian and differing

\end{question}

see original posting [here](https://www.manhattanprep.com/gmat/forums/1000sc-762-t1787.html).

The correct answer is (E) but my native language experience tells me (D) is much better, because "was differing" makes far less sense. Why is it that parallelism cannot happen between "was" and "differed" here, but has to happen between "determined" and "differed"? Are there any explicit rules in established grammar reference that forbids conjunction between active and passive voice? What about a casual sentence like "I got up and was greeted by my dog"?

EDIT: Peter has pointed out the real issue here is that "determined" is used as a modifier rather than a verb here. So clearly D is ruled out since "differ" can only be used in an active voice sense here.

Comment: Ah you are right. Apologize for my careless reading. Please feel free to downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A) and (B) are incorrect because you should say *local times were* and not *local times was*.

(C) is incorrect because *were determined* is not parallel to *differing*.

In (D) and (E), *determined* is not a verb but an adjective. You can't use *differed* because that's generally not used as an adjective in English (one uses *different* instead); however, *differing* can function as an adjective.

In my opinion, the best way of phrasing this sentence would be to take (B) and change *was* to *were*. But that's not one of the options.

Answer (score 0):

E is correct because of the tense of differ. It is present tense and will always be present tense. Local meridian time was not a thing of the past, it still happens.

Use of local times may be in the past, but the meridian times differing from city to city remains today.